# Advantages to not splitting small(ish) classes into separate files?

Tags: delphi

I have an "uObjects" unit. It has a several different types objects that extend TCollection/TCollectionItem. At one time having all these little bitty classes all grouped in one file probably made a ton of sense because things were small and they are kind of related and then you don't have a bajillion files to worry about.

But over time more and more methods have been added to some of these collections, making it harder to manage, so I'm thinking of breaking up the uObjects unit into multiple smaller units to make it more maintainable.

But before I do, I was wondering whether there are any caveats I should know about. Is this something I should go ahead and do without abandon? Or are there any reasons I might (perhaps in some cases) not want to break a unit's unrelated parts up into multiple units? Problems this could introduce down the road? I'm still trying to wrap my head around the nuances of Units, coming from the world of Java, where having multiple classes in a single file is not typically an option.

Comment: You might loose the direct/simple access to protected procedures/properties... if on class uses this from another.

Comment: TCollection + TCollectionItem... this could sound a lot like some business object set of classes I used for years myself. I'd go for the separate units. It smells better. Delphi classes in the same units are automatically friends (in C++ sense) to one another. If you do not need this, then separating units guarantees you won't access private/protected members just by oversight. Interfaces are cleaner... you have less unwanted/unneeded dependencies among your classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue is of circular dependency. Suppose you have these classes:

```
type
  TClass2 = class;

  TClass1 = class
    FObj1 = TClass2;
  end;

  TClass2 = class
    FObj2 = TClass1;
  end;
```

As written here, the circular dependency ties these classes to appear in the same file. That's because the circular dependency is only possible with a forward declaration. And forward declarations cannot apply across multiple files.

The other issue you may come across is private and protected member visibility. Within the same file, private and protected members defined in that file are always visible to other code in that file. This is a special exception to normal visibility rules that is a feature of Delphi.

When you move the classes to different files you might find that compilation fails due to private and protected members in other classes no longer being visible.

The Delphi idioms regarding class/file relationships differ in comparison to Java. Classes that work closely together are usually defined in the same file. On the other hand if class A exists fine without knowledge of class B then these two classes can usually be placed in different files.

Comment: I think the member visibility should not be an issue in a well-organized project. Private members should not be visible/referenced by other classes and protected member should only be visible/referenced by descendant classes. From this point of view breaking huge units into more smaller ones only helps to avoid irrational referencing. I personally prefer the one-class-per-unit modell with the exception of collection-, parameter- and helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Delphi version you could let go of the collections all together en move to generics instead. You would keep the, slightly reworked, collectionitem and put it in a TList (or similar).

Once you do that you will find you will lose most of the small classes (namely the `TCollections`). I would separate the remaining ones into different units.

When using TCollection I found that it was mostly because generics were not yet available.

A small example:

```
TMyCollectionItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  // Declarations
end;

TMyCollection = class(TCollection)
  // Declarations
end;

var
  MyCollection: TMyCollection;

/***************************/
// would become the following
/***************************/

TMyItem = class
  // Less declarations, as the typical TCollectionItem overrides are no longer required.
end;

var
  MyCollection: TList<TMyItem>;
```

I found this cleaned up a lot of my code.

Comment: Yep, this is the case of code that was originally written for Delphi 5-7 that's been ported to XE4

Comment: If you have methods that apply to the TCollection (for example, for  searching through the collection based on various criterion or clearing some flag from all list items, etc, would those just end up as random methods of the class using the TList?

Comment: You could add an anonymous sort method or even a class helper for that, but be careful of the scope as only the most recent helper will be used. You could of course also derive from TList<T> and add support methods there. That would still be better than the old TCollection.